# Htaccess redirect is not working in my site

Tags: .htaccess

Iam trying to redirect the url

mysite/love/this-is-another-question-about-lurv/29481751ffe886a64f9b0c9a

to

`mysite/question.php?qkey=29481751ffe886a64f9b0c9a`.

Iam using the following rewrite rule, but it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([\w]+)/([\w]+)/^([\w]+) question.php?cat=$1&qtitle=$2&qkey=$3
```

Comment: When debugging issues like this, it is easiest if you use a RegEx visualiser like http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/. Run your RegEx against your target string and you could see straight away what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, a dash character isn't considered a word character, try:

```
RewriteRule ([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/^([\w-]+) question.php?cat=$1&qtitle=$2&qkey=$3
```

also I'm not sure what function that caret is playing in the last part.  Outside of a [] it's normally used to indicate the start of a line, if that's the case here, than it would necessarily fail.

in which case:

```
RewriteRule ([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+) question.php?cat=$1&qtitle=$2&qkey=$3
```

may perhaps be a working solution.  I'd double check that - is a word character.